# DWR like Javascript library for REST

Tags: javascript, rest, jersey, dwr

Is there a Javascript library like DWR that can generate javascript stub for REST api. We are using Jersey/JSR-311 for REST on server and was wondering that instead of using libraries like Jquery or dojo if there is a library that can take a Rest class annotated using JSR311 annotations and create javascript stub like DWR does?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like one of the big benefits of RESTEasy over Jersey.  See http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/AJAX_Client.html for more info.

I don't know whether the functionality works on Jersey or not.

What I'd like to see: Generated API test pages for REST and SOAP pages, like .NET has.

Answer (score 0):

I am about to commit such a thing for [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/), the JBoss implementation of JAX-RS. You can expect it within a month. It might even become portable and work for Jersey if there is traction.